# If soy and eres mean "I am" and "you are", when should you use "yo soy" and "tú eres"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, sintaxis

Knowing that verbs imply the subject (unlike English), when is it necessary to be redundant and use the subject? I gathered that it is only used at the beginning of a conversation, but I'm not sure.

> Soy alto (inteligente, moreno, etc.)
>
> vs.
>
> Yo soy alto (inteligente, moreno, etc.)

Also applies to "tú eres", "el(la) es", "nosotros somos", etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, we specify the subject for emphasis. Using your examples:

> Soy alto (inteligente, moreno, etc.)

In this sentence, I am specifying one of my characteristics, which are the important part of the sentence. I don't need to specify the subject, since it is inferred from the verb.

> Yo soy alto (inteligente, moreno, etc.)

Subtly different: once again, I am specifying a characteristic of mine, but I have put some emphasis on the subject, by mentioning it when it is unnecessary. By putting more importance on the subject, I am making it stand out.

For instance, if we are about to meet for the first time and you ask me how will you recognise me among a group, I may answer:

> Yo soy alto, moreno y llevo gafas.

With this, I am implying that I will be the only one in that group that meets the description (if you see someone with these characteristics, that's me). If, on the other hand, I answer:

> Soy alto, moreno y llevo gafas.

I am describing myself, hoping that this will help you, but I am not implying anything about other people in the group (maybe because I don't know who else will be there).

As you can see, this is a subtle difference. In case of doubt, you are generally better off by not mentioning the subject.

Comment: *In case of doubt, you are generally better off by not mentioning the subject.* <-- That was the most helpful part ;) thanks for the explanations.

Comment: ^^ This is what I teach my students.  It serves a double purpose too, both being the norm and forcing them to pay attention to verb endings rather than using the pronouns as a crutch.  Probably the best rule of the thumb for English-speakers is if you would stress the pronoun in speech or italicize it in writing, go ahead and use it.  Otherwise, omit.

Comment: Indeed, specifying the subject (especially when it is *yo*) a lot makes you appear as egotistic. Though, if you are a foreigner, people will understand that you are not yet used to these nuances. If any, they will identify you as an English-speaking person who must always use the subject in his native language.